# Wi-Fi credentials across two distant routers

Tags: wireless-networking

Two identical ASUS routers are deployed in different cities.  Both are configured with the same SSID and password. A Raspbian Raspberry Pi configured with Wi-Fi credentials in the first city and shipped to the second city.

Will the device connect to the second identical router's Wi-Fi automatically? Or is there some obstacle that prevents this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is in fact how roaming works on a Wi-Fi network with multiple APs. Wireless clients look for any AP publishing the network name (SSID) that the client has been configured to join. If the client finds any AP that has the right security type and passphrase that the client has been configured for, then the client will join it. There's no magic to it. The APs don't have to have anything else in common except SSID, security type, and passphrase.